# I am getting exception while passing Date to the controller - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I want to search records for two dates from the database with spring JDBC. I used where `startDate=?` and `endDate=?` I need to correct the controller. I am getting exception as

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver resolveException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]


**`viewemp?start=2021-08-30&end=2021-09-24`**
```

```
public class EmpDao {  
JdbcTemplate template;  
  
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  

public List<Event> getEmployees(Date start, Date end){  
    return template.query("select * from Event where startDate=? and endDate=?",new RowMapper<Event>(){  
        public Event mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {  
            Event e=new Event();  
            e.setEventName(rs.getString(1));  
            e.setEventOrgName(rs.getString(2));  
            e.setEventFare(rs.getInt(3));  
            e.setStartDate(rs.getDate(4));
            e.setEndDate(rs.getDate(5));
            return e;  
        }  
    });  
}  
}    



public class Event {  
private String eventName;  
private String eventOrgName;  
private int eventFare;  
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;

} 



@Controller  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;
   
   @GetMapping("/viewemp")  
public String viewemp(@RequestParam(value="start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") Date start,
        @RequestParam(value="end") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") Date end, Model m){  
    List<Event> list=dao.getEmployees(start,end);  
    
    m.addAttribute("list",list);
    return "viewemp";  
}  
    
}





<h1>Add New Employee</h1>
       <form method="get" action="viewemp">  
       <input type="date" id="start" name="start"/>
        <input type="date" id="end" name="end"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        
        </form>
```

Comment: Please use something other than `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your XML. You may missed     <mvc:annotation-driven /> to include.
And controller change to

```
@RestController  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;
   
    @PostMapping("/viewemp")
    public String viewemp(@RequestParam(value="start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date start,
                          @RequestParam(value="end") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date end, Model m){
        List<Event> list=dao.getEmployees(start,end);  
    
    m.addAttribute("list",list);
    return "viewemp";
}
}
```